# How to show notification in the background in a particular future day using AlarmManager

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm showing a DatePicker to make the user select date in the future, and I want to notify the user one day before the selected date. For example, if the user selects the date [Apr 26, 2020] I want to notify the user in [Apr 25, 2020] even if the app is not running. However, in my case, the notification appears just when the app is running, but when the app is not running notification doesn't work.

**This is my MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US)

        edit_text_date.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePicker()
        }
        notify_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                val deadlineDate = dateFormat.parse(edit_text_date.text.toString())!!
                val c = Calendar.getInstance()
                c.time = deadlineDate
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
                val pastDay = dateFormat.format(c.time)
                val calender = Calendar.getInstance()
                val currentDate = dateFormat.format(calender.time)
                if (currentDate == pastDay) {
                    val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
                    alarmManager.set(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        c.timeInMillis,
                        pendingIntent
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showDatePicker() {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        DatePickerDialog(this,DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                val daySelected = Calendar.getInstance()
                daySelected.apply {
                    set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                    set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
                    set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                }
                edit_text_date.setText(dateFormat.format(daySelected.time))
            },
            c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ).show()
    }
}
```

**This is AlarmReceiver class**

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        showNotification(context,"title","notification message")

    }
    private fun showNotification(context: Context,title:String,body:String){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID","My Channel",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)!!
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }
        val notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"CHANNEL_ID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build()
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(0,notification)
    }
}
```

I also register the reciever in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

To schedule tasks more efficiently, you should use the newly introduced WorkManager class.
It handles all API levels and you don't have to worry about Android Versions that your application will work on.

To call your function at a set desired time,

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerClass.class)
                                                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                                                        .setInitialDelay(delayToPass, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                                        .build();
WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
    .enqueueUniqueWork(oneTimeWorkRequest);
```

For more information check out: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager

"WorkerClass" is a class that will handle your desired work inside the

```
public Result doWork() // method
```

Make sure you read about it too.